# MySQL fulltext search only scores above zero

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

If I have a fulltext query like this:

```
SELECT title,
   MATCH(question) AGAINST ('string') AS q_score,
   MATCH(answer) AGAINST ('string') AS a_score,
   MATCH(keywords) AGAINST ('string') AS kw_score FROM helptable
   ORDER BY (4 * q_score) + (1 * a_score) + (2 * kw_score) DESC
```

That works, I get a relevancy ranked result.

However I don't want any results with a combined score of 0. But when I try to add something like:

```
   WHERE a_score > 0
```

It doesn't work ("#1054 - Unknown column 'a_score' in 'where clause'"). Is there a different way to do this? Thank you!

(MariaDB 10.4.10, InnoDB table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT title,
       MATCH(question) AGAINST ('string') AS q_score,
       MATCH(answer) AGAINST ('string') AS a_score,
       MATCH(keywords) AGAINST ('string') AS kw_score
FROM helptable
HAVING a_score > 0
ORDER BY (4 * q_score) + (1 * a_score) + (2 * kw_score) DESC;
```

MySQL extends the use of the `HAVING` clause so it can be used in non-aggregation queries.  MySQL also allows the use of column aliases in the `HAVING` clause.  Voila!  This does what you want.

I'm not sure what you mean by "combined score", but you can add additional conditions as well:

```
HAVING a_score > 0 OR kw_score > 0
```